# How to play a fullscreen video on click ? (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, video, fullscreen

I've an image with a fake play button on it and I would want to open a fullscreen video on play click button.

I precise I've the video on local file.

I'm using angular for my website, I don't know if it's possible.

Thanks guys,

Nam's

Comment: Most important is where the video resides: Youtube, Vimeo, local file? You should look into https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have the video on local file do you know how to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use background video plugins like-

https://github.com/caseyhen/background-video

Comment: Thanks man but I dont want to use it as a video background. I just want to open the fullscreen video on click and I also would quit it on escap

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at https://github.com/videojs/video.js

Essentially, you add this to your webpage:

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.0/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.0/video.min.js"></script>
```

And then, place this element where you want your player. Change the values according to your need (size, poster image, paths).

```
<video id="really-cool-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
 preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="really-cool-video-poster.jpg"
 data-setup='{}'>
  <source src="really-cool-video.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
  <source src="really-cool-video.webm" type='video/webm'>
  <p class="vjs-no-js">
    To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser
    that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
  </p>
</video>
```

If you want to use more options (autoplay, preload, etc), you can either add them as data attribute like the height & poster, or add them to the **data-setup** separated by commas, like so:

```
<video id="really-cool-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
     preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="really-cool-video-poster.jpg"
     data-setup='{ "autoplay": true, "preload": "auto"}'>
```

You can look at possible option there: http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/options.html

Comment: Thanks Kuzyn for your help. My first idea was to use an image with a play button in the middle and to open the full screen video on click on this button. Anyway I'm going to try to use <video> but do you know how to open it on fullscreen ?

Comment: I would discourage going automatically into fullscreen, as it generally create bad user experience and might be problematic on some device. However you could look into binding the fullcreen method to a bind event or something along this. See http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/api.html . And I mean, just read the doc it's all in there.